# Using React.forwardRef() unnecessary could get any disadvantage?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using my custom Button Component.

Until before I don't need the `ref` in my Button Component.

But now I have to make it support `ref`.

So, I've added `React.forwardRef()` at the code.

And it works well.

This is my example.

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  children?: string | number | React.ReactNode;
  style?: CSSProperties;
  className?: string;
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  block?: boolean;
}

export const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(({disabled, onClick = ()=>{}, className, block, style, children}, ref ) => {
  return (
   <button ref={ref} disabled={disabled} onClick={onClick} className={`Button ${className} ${block ? '--block' : ''}`} style={style}>
     {children}
   </button>
 )});
```

In my project, I am using over 100 the Button components,

But only a few components need the `ref`.

It means almost all Button don't need `React.forwardRef()`.

Is it okay the component using like above? or

Should I have to separate the component follow the use?

Comment: Absolutely not, This is what forwardRef is  used for: forward the ref if provided.

Comment: @Incepter You mean I should use the `forwardRef` for ref only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forwardRef is so useful: It is a great api to make an abstraction of over a dom element while providing the ability to access the dom elements.

Popular ui libraries exports most of their component as `forwardRef`s. Because it will give developers the ability to have access to the dom element. So I think you took a good decision by making your `Button` component a `forwardRef`: It gives the developer the ability to access to the dom `button` element if needed.